# CSS rotation out of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I try to rotate a div with the css, the div left and top position make my div is out of the window. here is the snippet to illustrate it :

```js
document.getElementById('test').style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('test').style['-moz-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('test').style['-o-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('test').style['-ms-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('test').style['transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('test').style['zoom'] = '150%';
```

```css
div {
  width : 200px;
  height : 100px;
  border : red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

On my true project, my problem is applicated to the top and the left of my div, but in the snippet you can see that the problem is applicated to the top.

Also, I need to zoom the div to correspond to the window height and width. Usually I use : window.height * 100 / div.height and it works, but how can I make the div left and top correspond to the window left and top ?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: document.getElementById('test').style['zoom'] = '150%'; - if you comment out this line, your div pops back to top left. Not an answer, but hopefully points you in the right direction.

Comment: Weird, when i did the snippet, i tried my code without the zoom and i had the problem anyway. Then i remembered that i wanted to zoom too so i add the zoom line after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall setup the axis of rotation. This can be done with CSS. Example:

```
transform-origin: 100px 100px
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you explain me deeper the origin ? What's mean the two '100px' ?

Comment: The transform-origin is the point around which the element will rotate.  To rotate around the center of your (200px wide, 100px tall) element you'd want `transform-origin: 100px 50px;`.

Comment: Ok but, because of my div have a variable width and height, i can't fix an only origin for my project. How do you think i can do to make the left top corner of my div, when she was rotated, matches with the left top of my window ?

Comment: If you use your left top corner as axis, your whole content of the page will rotate out of the screen. But if you want so, you can use `transform-origin: left top;` - this will place axis of rotation to the left top corner of the div you want to rotate.